# Using a debugger and curses at the same time?

Tags: python, exception, interpreter, curses, pdb

I'm calling `python -m pdb myapp.py`, when an exception fires, and I'd normally be thrown back to the pdb interpreter to investigate the problem. However this exception is being thrown after I've called through `curses.wrapper()` and entered curses mode, rendering the pdb interpreter useless. How can I work around this?

Comment: i think there might be useful infomation http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggers

Comment: I got a laugh at the title of this. Yeah debugging and cursing seem to go together in my mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

James` answer is a good and I've upvoted it but I'd also consider trying to split the logic and presentation layers of my program. Keep the curses part a thin layer on top of a library and write a simple driver that invokes the correct routines to recreate the error. Then you can dive in and do what's necessary.

Another way I can think of is to create a function called `debug` or something that throws you back into the regular screen and invokes pdb. Then stick it just before the code that raises the exception and run your program. Something like

```
def debug(stdscr):
    curses.nocbreak()
    stdscr.keypad(0)
    curses.echo()
    curses.endwin()
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Apparently, this is similar to what is done with the `curses.wrapper` function. It's mentioned briefly at http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/curses/.

Comment: A wise suggestion to keep the curses logic separated, and thanks for the `curses.wrapper` pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Not being familiar with Python, this may not be exactly what you want. But apparently, winpdb can attach to a script - just like gdb can to a running process (IIUC).

http://winpdb.org/docs/launch-time/

Don't be mislead by the name, it is platform independent.

Comment: Good suggestion. You beat me to this. It would be the right way to go about this problem. Also useful for GUIs and daemon processes.

Comment: I don't suppose it's possible to attach using the core library's pdb?

Comment: I don't think so. You'll need to use winpdb on the 'client' and the 'server'.

Comment: As of Dec 2023, winpdb is gone, but look for winpdb-reborn instead. This is a Python3 port of winpdb.

Answer (score 0):

use pyclewn

you can use [pyclewn](http://pyclewn.sourceforge.net) with vim. 
or use pdb-clone,the core of pyclewn
its good ,its like gdb ,can remote debug

Comment: Pyclewn is not supported anymore according to that link.